# Rotation script issues?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is called when the user release the mouse button:

```
float rot_duration = 3f;
float rot_speed = 1.8f;
Quaternion final_rot;

void Start()
{
    cubeMesh = GameObject.FindWithTag("CubeMesh");

    Vector3 initial_rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    final_rot = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(initial_rot.x, initial_rot.y, 180));
}

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) 
    {
        StartCoroutine (DelayRotate (0.1F));
    }
}

IEnumerator DelayRotate(float waitTime)
{
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
        float rot_elapsedTime = 0.0F;
        while (rot_elapsedTime < rot_duration) {
        cubeMesh.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, final_rot, rot_elapsedTime);
            rot_elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime * rot_speed;
            yield return null;
        }
}
```

This script makes a GameObject rotate, 0.1 seconds after mouse button release. The problem is that it "flips" the GameObject quickly then starts rotating.

I believe it is flipping due to `final_rot2 = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(initial_rot.x, initial_rot.y, 180));` (because of `180` value) What should I do instead?

Comment: @Prix The `while` needs to be there or else it won't rotate.

Comment: never use quaternions ***for any reason - ever***.  use the `Rotate` call.  transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);  many examples right here http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: What is final_rot initialized to?

Comment: @Programmer question edited.

Comment: I found the mistake in your code. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at code carefully and I was able to spot **two** mistakes.

**1.** The **one** mistake that is causing the problem is:

```
cubeMesh.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, final_rot, rot_elapsedTime);
```

The guy above me said you should **replace** `transform.rotation` with `cubeMesh.transform.rotation`. That is close but **wont** work. What you are **suppose** to is to **get** the **current** position of the GameObject **outside** the `while loop` and store it somewhere, then you can use it **later** on inside the `while loop`. For example,

```
Quaternion currentLocation = cubeMesh.transform.rotation;
while(...){
  cubeMesh.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (currentLocation, final_rot, rot_elapsedTime);
...Other codes
}
```

**2.** **Another** **mistake** I found is that it looks like you are trying to rotate the object within time because you have a variable called `rot_duration`.

If this is true then you failed when you did `Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, final_rot, rot_elapsedTime);`.

If you want the object to rotate within `rot_duration` amount of time, change `rot_elapsedTime` to `rot_elapsedTime / rot_duration`. Also **remove** `rot_speed` as that will **NOT** work if you want to rotate over time.

If this is **NOT** what you are trying to do then the **first** mistake I found should fix your problem.

Your final Code should look like something below:

```
float rot_duration = 10f;
float rot_speed = 3f;
Quaternion final_rot;
GameObject cubeMesh;

void Start()
{
    cubeMesh = GameObject.FindWithTag("CubeMesh");

    Vector3 initial_rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    final_rot = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(initial_rot.x, initial_rot.y, 180));
}

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Delay(1));
    }
}

IEnumerator Delay(float waitTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    float rot_elapsedTime = 0.0F;

    //Get the current rotation 
    Quaternion currentLocation = cubeMesh.transform.rotation;

    while (rot_elapsedTime < rot_duration)
    {
        rot_elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        cubeMesh.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(currentLocation, final_rot, rot_elapsedTime / rot_duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this doesn't update for each frame. I see that you add Time.deltaTime, but it doesn't update per frame, it only uses the value for the current frame several times, since you do everything in one update.

This code might work:

```
float rot_duration = 10f;
float rot_speed = 3f;
float rot_elapsedTime = 3f;
Quaternion final_rot;

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) 
    {
        StartCoroutine (Delay (1));
    }
    if (rot_elapsedTime < rot_duration) {
        cubeMesh.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, final_rot, rot_elapsedTime);
        rot_elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime * rot_speed;
}

IEnumerator Delay(float waitTime)
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
   rot_elapsedTime = 0.0F;
}
```

But as being said, transform.Rotate is probably better.

Edit: Updated after OP's edit with new code, adding a 1 sec delay.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the 1 sec delay at first, but still I think your problem is that you have a while loop, which means that you are doing the whole rotation at once, without the frame updating. I have edited my answer to your new code.

Comment: His while loop is not a problem, it yields return null, which will do the same as WaitForEndOfFrame()